# Run in Postman from application

Tags: node.js, http, postman

When test my server in Postman, the status is 404 NOT_FOUND:

> {"error":{"statusCode":404,"name":"Error","message":"Shared class 
>   \"App\" has no method handling GET
>   /56fd2bf04fbf42f357f6b112/versions","stack":"Error: Shared class 
>   \"App\" has no method handling GET
>   /56fd2bf04fbf42f357f6b112/versions\n    at restRemoteMethodNotFound
>   (D:\PKL\cyclone-backend\node_modules\strong-remoting\lib\rest-adapter.js:388:17)\n
>   at Layer.handle [as handle_request]
>   (D:\PKL\cyclone-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)\n
>   at trim_prefix
>   (D:\PKL\cyclone-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)\n
>   at
>   D:\PKL\cyclone-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7\n
>   at Function.process_params
>   (D:\PKL\cyclone-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)\n
>   at next
>   (D:\PKL\cyclone-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)\n
>   at Function.handle
>   (D:\PKL\cyclone-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)\n
>   at router
>   (D:\PKL\cyclone-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)\n
>   at Layer.handle [as handle_request]
>   (D:\PKL\cyclone-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)\n
>   at trim_prefix
>   (D:\PKL\cyclone-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)\n
>   at
>   D:\PKL\cyclone-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7\n
>   at Function.process_params
>   (D:\PKL\cyclone-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)\n
>   at next
>   (D:\PKL\cyclone-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)\n
>   at jsonParser
>   (D:\PKL\cyclone-backend\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:103:7)\n
>   at Layer.handle [as handle_request]
>   (D:\PKL\cyclone-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)\n
>   at trim_prefix
>   (D:\PKL\cyclone-backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)"}}

[Screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdhBV.png)

Comment: it looks like your application route does not support GET request, try changing the request method to POST and "post" the needed parameters, or replace :id parameter with some value if using GET method.

Comment: okay, thanks for your answer. I got this :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically `404` requests are typically due to wrong URLs entered or wrong HTTP methods. You can double check on them both and you should find the solution.